# c++ allocator traits reference and const_reference missing and iterator to const iterator conversion

Tags: c++, containers, c++17, type-traits, const-iterator

I am trying to implement a custom std compliant container class with an iterator.
To do so, i started to define the public type definitions to be used by traits for the container class as well as the iterator.
I want to make it c++17 compliant and try to not use c++20 removed features or c++17 deprecated.
This is what i got:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class container {
    using allocator_type = Alloc;
    using value_type = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::value_type;
    using pointer = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer;
    using const_pointer = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::const_pointer;
    using reference = value_type&; // <-- here 
    using const_reference = const value_type&; // <-- here 
    using difference_type = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::difference_type;
    using size_type = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::size_type;

    class iterator;
};

template <typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class container::iterator {
    using value_type = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::value_type;
    using pointer = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer;
    using const_pointer = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::const_pointer;
    using reference = value_type&; // <-- here 
    using const_reference = const value_type&; // <-- here
    using difference_type = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::difference_type;
    using size_type = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::size_type;
};
```

Do i have to define reference and const_reference types myself like i did in the example or is there another std way of doint it?
Another question would be how to define a const_iterator without duplicating my iterator.
Some say that i should template my iterator with the value type, some just write a new iterator.
If i would template i dont know how i would create the right type traits for it, so my function definitions for the std:
`reference operator*() const` and `pointer operator->() const`,
because `reference` would be `const_reference` and `const_reference` would be technically `const const_reference`.
For example:

```
template <typename T>
class container {
    
    template <typename ValueType>
    class iterator;

    using iterator = iterator<T>;
    using const_iterator = iterator<const T>;
};

template <typename ValueType>
class container::iterator {
public:
    using value_type = ValueType;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using const_pointer = const value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using const_reference = const value_type&;

    reference operator*() const;
    pointer operator->() const;
};
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate. your question is a little bit wage

Comment: What do you mean by "i should template my iterator"?

Comment: BTW Shouldn't ```value_type``` be simply ```T```?

Comment: Yes it will be, but the examples i found on the net and also the boost implementions used the allocator_traits so i thought maybe its helpful for something..., i could define all of the types only with T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i have to define reference and const_reference types myself like i did in the example

Yes. The allocator doesn't know how your container is implemented, so it cannot know how to define those type aliases.

> Another question would be how to define a const_iterator without duplicating my iterator.

With the magic of templates. `iterator<T>` vs `iterator<const T>`.

> because reference would be const_reference and const_reference would be technically const const_reference

That's not a problem as long as `const_reference` is `const T&` because due to const folding rules `const const_reference` is simply `const T&` which is what you would want.

Comment: defining the types const_pointer the iterator template would result in: `const const T*`. Is this valid?

Comment: @Lessi if type alias `X = const T`, then `const X` is simply `const T` and is valid.